# Buttons not rendering when I try to connect to Dropbox using the Javascript API

Tags: javascript, html, dropbox

I want to connect to Dropbox using Javascript.  This is part of a lab that I'm doing.

I have the code below, and I have checked it for syntax errors and haven't found any.  However, it doesn't display the buttons I expected.

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the code as it is now: https://jsfiddle.net/gv19a3mw/15/

And here is a Fiddle showing the layout I expected (with no Javascript executing): https://jsfiddle.net/gv19a3mw/12/

Can anyone advise me why the buttons are not displaying when my Javascript is executing?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/dropbox-datastores-1.2-latest.js">
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#w_area').hide();
      $('#r_area').hide();

      // Create a dropbox client
      var client = new Dropbox.client({key: "pbio1kig5q73lli"});

      // Authenticate the client
      client.authenticate({interactive: false}, function(error, client) {
        if (error) {
          alert("Authentication error: " + error);
          }
        });

      // Show w_area if login ok
//      alert(client.isAuthenticated());
      if (client.isAuthenticated()) {
        $('#w_area').show();
      };


      // Write to myfile.txt in Dropbox
      $('#w_button').click(function() {
        client.authenticate({interactive: true}, function(error, client) {
          if (error) {
            alert("Authentication error: " + error);
          }
          else {
            client.writeFile("myfile.txt", $('textarea#w_content').val(), function(error) {
              if (error) {
            alert("Write error: " + error);
            }
            else {
              alert("File written successfully!");
              $('#r_area').show();
            }
          });
          }
        });
      });

      // Read from myfile.txt from Dropbox
      $('#r_button').click(function() {
        client.authenticate({interactive: true}, function(error, client) {
          if (error) {
            alert("Authentication error: " + error);
          }
          else {
            client.readFile("myfile.txt", {}, function(error, data) {
              if (error) {
                alert("Read error: " + error);
              }
              else {
                alert("File read successfully!");
                $('textarea#r_content').val(data);
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });
    })
  </script>
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <h3>File Read/Write in Dropbox</h3>

  <div id="w_area">
    <textarea id="w_content" cols="50" rows="5">
    </textarea>
    <button id="w_button">
      Write to File in Dropbox
    </button>
    <br /><br />
  </div>

  <div id="r_area">
    <textarea id="r_content" cols="50" rows="5">
    </textarea>
    <button id="r_button">
      Read from File in Dropbox
    </button>
    <br /><br />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying you're getting syntax errors?

Comment: no. My english is not very well sorry. I am saying that I checked it once and it do not have any syntax errors.

Comment: Hello. Your question came up in the 'Help and improvement' editing queue. It was a little difficult to answer as it was, so I have edited the English and title to make it more likely that people with the knowledge to help you will see it. Your code was formatted OK and easy to understand and we can see that you have tried some error checking using the `alert`. I've added a couple of JSFiddle links for your code - they are a good way to show what is happening now and what you would like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove buttons from element `div#w_area`  and `div#r_area`

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#w_area').hide();
 $('#r_area').hide();
```

Because of this code your buttons are nor visible.

Comment: remove element = delete  $('#w_area').hide(); and $('#r_area').hide();?

Comment: Note - this will make the buttons appear, which answers the question as asked.  However, there may be deeper problems with the OP code - the reasons the elements didn't appear before is because the lines `$('#w_area').show();` and `$('#r_area').show();` are never being reached...